# Xorg broken? No network-manager in recovery after complete update (16.04)

Tags: boot, xorg, network-manager, intel-graphics, recovery-mode

This is my first question in a linux forum. So far I was able to find solutions to the many situations I faced since I moved to linux. To the point:

Situation:

Yesterday I ran a **dist-upgrade** after installing and running Intel's driver update tool (Intel Hd Graphic 3000). Rebooted and everything was fine. I did this hoping to sort out a problem with the hdmi output of my laptop. Then I went further and did an **upgrade** and **auto-remove** then i went to bed (bad idea).
Today I realized my laptop wasn't getting to the login screen. Modules were loading and the screen would go black you could see the pointer (not black as my theme) and the the screen would turn on and off every 2 sec. Nothing can be done but to shut it off. Same happens if I disable quiet mode and the splash screen. You can see the log but at a certain point it looses the tidy tabulation and starts to flash.

What I tried:

1) I assumed video driver was the issue. Thought of recovery mode to install the original drivers. However I'm handicapped because I can't seem to start the network. When I enter the '*enable networking*' entry if fails and I can see repetitions of

`grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`

2) Tried **iwconfig**but my netwok is WPA protected (not WEP as needed by iwconfig).

3) Tried wired net but i can only upstart my adapter 
`ifconfig eth0 up`
I can't enable dchp (**dhclient** fails, asks me to turn on WiFi!??).

4) Tried manually starting **NetworkManager** service through systemd: time out failure.

5) Tried **dpkg-reconfigure** with **resolvconf** (success?) and NetworkManager (did nothing, got stuck)

6) Tried manually symlinking *resolv.conf* from */etc/resolvconf*
but sometimes system sometimes doesn't acknoledge its existance. I cant even use gedit (sighs).

7) Last thing I tried was running **dist-upgrade** once more with files already in the computer. I'm waiting for a result.

So far it look my computer is just refusing to do anything. Even simple file managing stuff seems to behave weirdly. And without access to internet I'm pretty much cooked.

My questions:

1) Does it look like a problem with the video drivers is causing the screen to flash in a loop as if it's trying to init but fails? Could it be something else?

2) Is there a known reason why Network Manager can't start? Are there alternative methods to connect to internet? I'm going to turn my wan to WEP and test iwconfig again.

3) Would you recommend downloading **i915 driver** on a memory stick and manually installing it? Is it too risky? Where can I get a deb file?

4) If nothing works, is there a way to install Ubuntu over the existing system and keep configurations (sort of repair install)

I'd be so happy if you'd shed some light on this tricky problem. I can provide any info you need. Sorry for my noobness and thank you in advance.
Cheers

UPDATE: 
The last **dist-update** I ran in recovery mode (I don't even know how that managed to run without internet) fixed the screen flashing. Now I can get to the login screen but when I write my pass and hit enter I get no unity launcher. Only my background image and a small window reading `System program problem detected. Do you want to report the problem now?`. This quickly changes font and screen flashes toggling between my background image and black desktop with one icon and this window. I toggle CapsLock or turn on WiFi I get the usual pop up messages but the appear and disapear flashing. I can't get terminal or anything. Still stuck.   Networking still doesn't work in Recovery Mode.